# Having trouble displaying XML information through XSL in a table

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to display information whether static or calculated with functions in a table format.

Basically I have some team stats for several games were there is a home team and visiting team and only the games with a status of "played" should be figured into the scores, but I need to display them in a table ranked by their wins.

Here is the XML

```
    <Schedule xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <Teams>
            <Team>Blue Jays</Team>
        </Teams>



        <Game> 
            <Home_Team>Blue Jays</Home_Team>
            <Away_Team>Marlins</Away_Team>
            <Date>2012-01-10</Date>
            <Home_Team_Score>7</Home_Team_Score>
            <Away_Team_Score>9</Away_Team_Score>
        </Game>
```

Here is the XSL that I am trying to get to display the table

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0"/>
    <xsl:key name="team" match="Teams" use="Team"/>

    <xsl:template match="/Schedule">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title><xsl:value-of select="League"/>
                </title>
                <link href="batty.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="headliner"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="headliner">
        <h1>
            <xsl:value-of select="League"/>
        </h1>
        <h5>
            <th>put date here</th>
        </h5>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="scoreboard"/>
    </xsl:template>   
<xsl:template match="scoreboard">
    <table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" id="scores">
        <tr class="title">
            <th colspan="22">Season <xsl:value-of select="//Schedule[@season]"/></th>
        </tr>

        <tr class="fields">
            <th style="text-align: left">Team</th>
            <th>Rank</th>
            <th>Wins</th>
            <th>Losses</th>
            <th>Ties</th>
            <th>Points Earned</th>
            <th>Points Against</th>
            <th>Win %</th>
            <th>Games Behind</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rankingTeams">
            <xsl:call-template name="calcScores">
            </xsl:call-template>
        </tr>

    </table>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="calcScores">
    <xsl:variable name="wins" />
    <xsl:variable name="losses" />
    <xsl:variable name="ties" />
    <xsl:variable name="pointsEarned" />
    <xsl:variable name="winPercentage" />
    <xsl:variable name="gamesBehind" />
    <xsl:for-each
        select="//Teams[generate-id()=generate-id(key('team', Team)[1])]">
        <xsl:sort select="Team" />
        <h1><xsl:value-of select="Team" /></h1>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template> 
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am having trouble with the table even showing.  I can place the code from scoreboard template directly in the body and it will show, but not the way it is here when calling the template.

Then I am not sure how to go about calculating the wins and losses and so forth in my for-each loop

Comment: It looks like your XML got cut off in the middle, after one game only and without closing the `<Schedule>` tag. Could you post a fuller example?

Comment: I just posted one full "Game" element to keep down the length. It just keeps repeating with different "Game" elements and finishes with the </Schedule> tag.

Comment: Well, it would be nice to see more, so we can have something to test with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me as if you are mixing up "template match" and "template name" here. You are matching the elements headliner and scoreboard which are not present in your source, but what you want to do seems like use those as a called template. I think you should read up on how to use templates in XSLT and what is the difference between match and name templates...

Also very strange is when you call calcscores, what should that do? Currently this would produce a h1 element for each team, inside a tr...does not seem as if it makes sense, I guess you want to generate a **tr** for each team.

Try this, maybe this will help you get started:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" version="4.0"/>
<xsl:key name="team" match="Teams" use="Team"/>

<xsl:template match="/Schedule">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>
                <xsl:value-of select="League"/>
            </title>
            <link href="batty.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:call-template name="headliner"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="scoreboard"/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="headliner">
    <h1>
        <xsl:value-of select="League"/>
    </h1>
    <h5>
        <th>put date here</th>
    </h5>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="scoreboard"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="scoreboard">
    <table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" id="scores">
        <tr class="title">
            <th colspan="22">Season <xsl:value-of select="//Schedule/@season"/></th>
        </tr>

        <tr class="fields">
            <th style="text-align: left">Team</th>
            <th>Rank</th>
            <th>Wins</th>
            <th>Losses</th>
            <th>Ties</th>
            <th>Points Earned</th>
            <th>Points Against</th>
            <th>Win %</th>
            <th>Games Behind</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//Teams">
            <xsl:sort select="Team"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Team">
    <tr class="rankingTeams">
        <td style="text-align: left">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
        <td><!-- Rank: no idea how you want to calculate this --></td>
        <td>
            <!-- Wins -->
            <xsl:variable name="homeWins"
                select="count(//Game[Home_Team=current()][Home_Team_Score &gt; Away_Team_Score])"
            />
            <xsl:variable name="awayWins"
                select="count(//Game[Away_Team=current()][Away_Team_Score &gt; Home_Team_Score])"
            />
            <xsl:value-of select="$homeWins + $awayWins"/>
        </td>
        <td><!-- Loses: similar to Wins --></td>
        <td><!-- Ties: similar to Wins --></td>
        <td><!-- Points Earned --></td>
        <td><!-- Points Against --></td>
        <td><!-- Win % --></td>
        <td><!-- Games Behind --></td>
    </tr>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you, that definitely got me going and I think I can figure out a lot of the calculations from there except the ranking which should be by number of wins, since this is not done in a for-each, how would it be sorted?

Comment: Also, how would I exclude all games but the ones with a "status" of "played"?

Comment: just use //Game[@status='Played'] to get only the played games, for the ranking I'm not sure if you can even do this with XSLT 1 in one step, because you need the number of wins before you can calculate the ranking...what are you using to do the transformation? can you use an XSLT 2 supported processor? That would make things a lot easier

Comment: I could use about anything, javascript, DOM, CSS, XSLT, I do need to do it without server based processing though.

Comment: Well than I'd suggest you generate everything but the Rank with XSLT and try yourself in a javascript function that calculates the rank... maybe take a look into how to make the table sortable, if you than sort it by wins you basically got the rank... if you do so you should open another question just for that than.

Comment: ...and check this one as answered ;)

Comment: If you start by generating the table rows in a variable, you can then sort these by their computed values in the second pass - all in the same stylesheet.

Comment: well with xslt 2 that's how I would've done it, but with xslt 1 you can not process nodesets in a variable, or can you??

Comment: Strictly speaking, no - but just about every XSLT 1.0 processor supports the EXSLT node-set() function.

Comment: That's still an extension and "just about every" is still not every...there's still a lot of xslt processors that don't and since the op mentioned he doesn't want to do any server side xslt processing there's even less of a choice.

Comment: "*there's still a lot of xslt processors that don't*" Can you name one? I said "just about every" because I may not be familiar with all of them out there - but I do know that node-set() is supported by libxslt, Xalan-C, Xalan-J, SAXON, Transformiix, Safari, Opera and the one MS processor I could find online. P.S. This is not my thread and If you don't address your comment to me, I don't get notified; I only discovered your reply by accident.